# can I use the chainlink oracle somehow at v.0.8.0?

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, oracles, chainlink

there are some functions on solidity i want to use for a project but I also need to use the chain-link oracle to get the latest price on a coin, and the chain-link oracle will only let me use it at 0.6.0

Comment: Did you check their repo? They have interfaces declared for several solc versions, for example https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/tree/develop/contracts/src/v0.8.

Answer (score 1):

The latest code snippets in the [docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/) use the v0.8 contracts